# Godot 4.2 Multiplayer, cant seem to sync a nodes position

Tags: godot, godot4

Quick explanation: I am making a fps multiplayer game, and I am attempting to add some procedural animations using code, I have setup the multiplayer from a youtube video and I have followed it to understand how things should work but this I am having issues with, so when I press the shoot button a vector3 receives some kickback, I have a function called "handle_kickback" which is just lerping its position to the kickback vector from the local window it works but when I attempt to see the other player play the animation it does nothing, I dont know why I can only guess, my guess is maybe the value for kick back is too small (0.2) and godot optimizes it out as useless data to send I dont really now...

other notes, I am using a MultiplayerSynchronizer node and I do have the container added if that makes any difference.

Here is a youtube video I made to get my issue across more easily, Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTIFavboxHY

Code:

```
class_name WeaponManager extends Node3D

@export var container : Node3D
@onready var weapon_cooldown : Timer = get_node("Weapon_Cooldown")

@export var kickback_start_position : Vector3
@export var kickback_end_position : Vector3

@export var kickback_speed : float = 2.0
@export var kickback_return_speed : float = 4.0
@export var not_shooting_return_speed : float = 1.5
var kickback_compensation : float = 0

func _process(delta):
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Action_Attack") and weapon_cooldown.is_stopped():
        weapon_cooldown.start()
        kickback_end_position.z = 0.2
        
    handle_kickback.rpc(delta)

@rpc("call_local")
func handle_kickback(delta : float) -> void:
    
    if container.position == Vector3.ZERO and kickback_end_position == Vector3.ZERO:
        return
    
    # if kickback end pos is vector3.zero we use return speed
    var speed : float = kickback_return_speed if kickback_end_position == Vector3.ZERO else kickback_speed
    
    
    if not Input.is_action_pressed("Action_Attack") and kickback_end_position == Vector3.ZERO:
        speed = not_shooting_return_speed
    
    kickback_compensation += speed * delta
    container.position = lerp(kickback_start_position,kickback_end_position,kickback_compensation)
    
    if kickback_compensation > 1.0:
        kickback_compensation = 0.0
        kickback_start_position = container.position
        kickback_end_position = Vector3.ZERO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: My knowledge of Godot multiplayer is very limited.

I see you use `rpc` with `handle_kickback`. Yet, I do not see you pass `kickback_end_position` to `handle_kickback`.

If I understand correctly you are synchronizing the `position` of the `container` with `MultiplayerSynchronizer`. Which makes me think that `handle_kickback` overwrites it based on a zero `kickback_end_position`.

I can think of three approaches to solve that issue:

- Following Godot's approach, I'd say add `kickback_end_position` to `MultiplayerSynchronizer`. If `kickback_end_position` is synchronized, you might let `handle_kickback` be purely local (no rpc) and working with the synchronized `kickback_end_position`.
- Alternatively, you could pass a vector offset to `handle_kickback`, so `handle_kickback` and only `handle_kickback` updates `kickback_end_position`.
- Or you could let `handle_kickback` be purely local (no rpc), and also not synchronize `kickback_end_position`... And instead have an additional method you call via rpc when the input is pressed, which updates `kickback_end_position`. This means that the value `kickback_end_position` would not be kept in sync, but since this is purely cosmetic, that might be OK.

With any of these approaches, you would have to remove the `position` of the `container` from the `MultiplayerSynchronizer`.

Comment: The first option worked perfectly, though removing position from the synchronizer actually stops it from working though is probably something else I can change, thanks for fixing my issue, can you explain a little bit more on why option 1 works by syncing the kickback end position vector?

Comment: @Dragon20C that would mean that both the `MultiplayerSynchronizer` updates the `position` and also `handle_kickback` updates the `position` the same way.  If `MultiplayerSynchronizer` has to update the `position`, maybe you do not need to synchronize `kickback_end_position`. That is, the solution would be simply not using rpc with `handle_kickback`. That way `handle_kickback` runs locally, it updates the `position` locally, and then `MultiplayerSynchronizer` synchronizes it.

Comment: I see, seems to be me not understanding what everything or how he multiplayer section of things work, thanks I understand a little bit more now!